# Can't access a string attribute from model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I tried to get a string attribute from my model to pass to javascript function that gets a String object but i keep getting an HTMLInputElement instead of string

```
<input type="radio" id="Paroxysmal" name="afeval" value="paroxysmal"> <label>Paroxysmal  </label> </br>
<input type="radio" id="Persistent" name="afeval" value="persistent"> <label>Persistent </label> <br>
<input type="radio" id="Permanent" name="afeval" value="permanent"> <label>Permanent  </label>

<script>                                   
    document.getElementById(@Model.Single(m => m.Diagnosis == "AF" && m.fieldType == "E").nameOf).checked=true;
</script>
```

From the model class:

```
public String nameOf { get; set; }
```

can i convert it do String? what else should i try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put @Model.... inside single quotes as shown below.

```
<script>                                   
   document.getElementById('@Model.Single(m => m.Diagnosis == "AF" && m.fieldType == "E").nameOf').checked=true;
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks,and if i want to pass it to function i.e:

                                      
                                    f('@Model.Single(m => m.Diagnosis == "AF" && m.fieldType == "E").nameOf');
j.s:
     function f(nameofID) {
    document.getElementById(nameofID).checked = true;
}
how can i do it?

Comment: just put '@Model...' value inside any variable and pass that variable to the function.....@VovaFeldstein

Comment: Thanks a lot,works great!..can you please explain why does this work like this?

Comment: because `getElementById` expects string and you have to use either single or double quotes as shown in answer.

Comment: but i tried to use @Model...toString() and (String)(@Model...) and new String(@Model...) isn't it the same?

Comment: @VovaFeldstein...these all are server side thing i.e concepts of c# but here you have to use client side things when you are inside javascript.

Comment: Thanks a lot a appreciate the help